# codeigniter net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a application build with CodeIgniter and I have error and my console shows me this:

> jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4 GET
> http://127.0.0.1/admin/assets/plugins/translate/application-en.json
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: have u set your base_url?

Comment: Check if there is an error in json?

Comment: yes, I do about base_url

Answer (score 3):

I had the same ERROR and had to write the config file like so:

`$config['base_url'] = getenv('BASE_URL');`.

Using getenv is optional of course, but in order to use **`<?php echo base_url(); ?>`** I needed to add to the application/config/config.php file.
According to the documentation [Codeigniter Config](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/config.html?highlight=config%20base_url)